# Check for zero or NULL in divisor

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'alina' THEN (COMMISSION*RATE/TOTAL_DAYS)  
        ELSE REWARD 
    END AS reward
FROM testing;
```

I need to check if `TOTAL_DAYS` is `0` or `NULL`. How can I do that? For the case of `NULL`, I can use `ISNULL` function.

But how can I check for both the cases `0` or `NULL`? In case of `TOTAL_DAYS` is `ZERO` or `NULL,` make `TOTAL_DAYS = 1`.

Comment: And if it's zero or NULL, what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
    select 
CASE 
    WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'alina' THEN  (COMMISSION * RATE/ISNULL(NULLIF(TOTAL_DAYS, 0), 1))  
    ELSE REWARD 
end as reward
    from testing;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`NULLIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) and [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'alina' THEN  (COMMISSION * RATE/ ISNULL(NULLIF(TOTAL_DAYS, 0), 1))  
        ELSE REWARD 
    END ASreward
FROM testing;
```

---

The `NULLIF` will return `NULL` if `TOTAL_DAYS` is `0`. Then, the `ISNULL` will return `1` if `NULLIF` returns `NULL`. Example:

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(N, 0), 1) AS N
FROM(
    VALUES (3), (NULL), (0)
)t(N)
```

This returns:

```
N
-----------
3
1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `coalesce` to translate a `null` to 1, and `greatest` to handle 0s:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'alina' 
            THEN commission * rate / GREATEST(COALESCE(total_days, 1), 1)
            ELSE reward END AS reward 
FROM testing;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one if it works.

```
        select 
    CASE 
        WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'alina' THEN CASE WHEN COALESCE(TOTAL_DAYS,0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (COMMISSION*RATE/TOTAL_DAYS)  
        ELSE REWARD 
    end as reward
        from testing;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'alina' THEN
        commission * rate / COALESCE(NULLIF(total_days, 0), 1)
    ELSE
        reward
    END AS reward 
FROM
    testing;
```